# List view doesnt keep color when scrolling up

Tags: java, android, xamarin

I'm using listview custom adapter which with row click i'm changing row color. But when i'm scrolling bot and up again it doesnt have the right position. 
It changes color in other rows...

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            DataViewHolder holder = null;
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.TableItems, null, false);
                holder = new DataViewHolder();
                holder.txtDescription = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtDescription);

                holder.txtDescription.Click += delegate
                {
                    holder.txtDescription.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Red);
                };
                convertView.Tag = holder;
            }
            else
            {
                holder = convertView.Tag as DataViewHolder;
            }
            holder.txtDescription.Text = mitems[position].Description;

            return convertView;
        }
        public class DataViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
        {
            public TextView txtDescription { get; set; }

        }
```

It looks like it doesnt keep in memory specific row situation.

Comment: Move Click outside `if-else`

Comment: It didnt work. It is like doesnt keep right item-visibility position

Comment: Move Click outside `if-else` and you have to check the previous state the toggle to opposite state, if you want to toggle between `VISIBLE/GONE` .

Comment: Should i check convertView? or   holder.BotLinear.Visibility?Should i use tag on its position?

Comment: `holder.BotLinear.Visibility`..

Comment: Sorry but i didnt understand. Also if i will change row color, it doesnt work neither.When i'm scrolling bot and up again i get everything in wrong position. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Please check updated question

Comment: Hi, I have provide for you a demo on [github](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/ListViewTest), please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the color in the click handler directly, instead change the data from which the adapter draws from and use that to change the color when GetView is called again.

`ListView` recycles the views it uses to optimize scrolling, instead it just expects the view to represent the data. If you change a color of one view directly, the view then gets recycled and you'll see "another view" (another part of the data) with a different background color.

So in summary: give each data point a color attribute and use that to set the color of each view in `GetView`, change the data and notify the adapter about the changes to the data.

**Edit**

I've never used Xamarin but maybe something like this would work

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    DataViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.TableItems, null, false);
        holder = new DataViewHolder();
        holder.txtDescription = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtDescription);

        holder.txtDescription.Click += delegate
        {
            // instead of setting the color directly here, just modify the data
            (holder.txtDescription.Tag as ItemType).ItemColor = Color.Red
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        };
        convertView.Tag = holder;
    }
    else
    {
        holder = convertView.Tag as DataViewHolder;
    }
    holder.txtDescription.Text = mitems[position].Description;
    holder.txtDescription.Tag = mitems[position];  // this so that the click handler knows which item to modify
    holder.txtDescription.SetBackgroundColor(mitems[position].ItemColor);

    return convertView;
}

public class DataViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
{
    public TextView txtDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Any help please

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` will reuse the item layout, you can use `List` and `View.Tag` to avoid the problem caused by reusing.

I have posted my demo on [github](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/ListViewTest).